# Is there any python bindings for android developers?

Tags: android, python

I am a python learner; would like to develop few applications in Android platform. Is there any Python bindings available for developing Android apps ?

Also I would like to know, Using python binding for development will make any performance overhead compared to java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to have a look at the [Kivy](https://kivy.org) project.

Wikipedia has [a bit to say about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kivy_(framework)), too.

Comment: The Wikipedia link is outdated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kivy_(framework)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ASE**

[Google Announce Android Scripting Environment](http://www.talkandroid.com/1225-android-scripting-environment/)

> The ASE allows developers to develop directly on the Android powered
>   device without the need for a separate computer using Android’s
>   development environment.
>
> Scripts can be run interactively in a terminal, started as a long
>   running service, or started via Locale. Python, Lua and BeanShell are
>   currently supported, and we’re planning to add Ruby and JavaScript
>   support, as well.

It can be downloaded from here:

> http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting